# Code Contracts Static Analysis: Prover Limitations?

Tags: c#, .net, static-analysis, code-contracts

I've been playing with Code Contracts and I really like what I've seen so far.  They encourage me to evaluate and explicitly declare my assumptions, which has already helped me to identify a few corner cases I hadn't considered in the code to which I'm adding contracts.  Right now I'm playing with trying to enforce more sophisticated invariants.  I have one case that currently fails proving and I'm curious if there is a way I can fix this besides simply adding Contract.Assume calls.  Here is the class in question, stripped down for ease of reading:

```
public abstract class MemoryEncoder
{
    private const int CapacityDelta = 16;

    private int _currentByte;

    /// <summary>
    ///   The current byte index in the encoding stream.
    ///   This should not need to be modified, under typical usage,
    ///   but can be used to randomly access the encoding region.
    /// </summary>
    public int CurrentByte
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 0);
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() <= Length);
            return _currentByte;
        }
        set
        {
            Contract.Requires(value >= 0);
            Contract.Requires(value <= Length);
            _currentByte = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Current number of bytes encoded in the buffer.
    ///   This may be less than the size of the buffer (capacity).
    /// </summary>
    public int Length { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The raw buffer encapsulated by the encoder.
    /// </summary>
    protected internal Byte[] Buffer { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reserve space in the encoder buffer for the specified number of new bytes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytesRequired">The number of bytes required</param>
    protected void ReserveSpace(int bytesRequired)
    {
        Contract.Requires(bytesRequired > 0);
        Contract.Ensures((Length - CurrentByte) >= bytesRequired);

        //Check if these bytes would overflow the current buffer););
        if ((CurrentByte + bytesRequired) > Buffer.Length)
        {
            //Create a new buffer with at least enough space for the additional bytes required
            var newBuffer = new Byte[Buffer.Length + Math.Max(bytesRequired, CapacityDelta)];

            //Copy the contents of the previous buffer and replace the original buffer reference
            Buffer.CopyTo(newBuffer, 0);
            Buffer = newBuffer;
        }

        //Check if the total length of written bytes has increased
        if ((CurrentByte + bytesRequired) > Length)
        {
            Length = CurrentByte + bytesRequired;
        }
    }

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void GlobalRules()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(Buffer != null);
        Contract.Invariant(Length <= Buffer.Length);
        Contract.Invariant(CurrentByte >= 0);
        Contract.Invariant(CurrentByte <= Length);
    }
}
```

I'm interested in how I can structure the Contract calls in ReserveSpace so that the class invariants are provable.  In particular, it complains about (Length <= Buffer.Length) and (CurrentByte <= Length).  It's reasonable to me that it can't see that (Length <= Buffer.Length) is satisfied, since it's creating a new buffer and reassigning the reference.  Is my only option to add an Assume that the invariants are satisfied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fighting with this for a while, I came up with this provable solution (constructor is a dummy to allow for isolated testing):

```
public abstract class MemoryEncoder
{
    private const int CapacityDelta = 16;

    private byte[] _buffer;
    private int _currentByte;
    private int _length;

    protected MemoryEncoder()
    {
        Buffer = new byte[500];
        Length = 0;
        CurrentByte = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   The current byte index in the encoding stream.
    ///   This should not need to be modified, under typical usage,
    ///   but can be used to randomly access the encoding region.
    /// </summary>
    public int CurrentByte
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentByte;
        }
        set
        {
            Contract.Requires(value >= 0);
            Contract.Requires(value <= Length);
            _currentByte = value;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    ///   Current number of bytes encoded in the buffer.
    ///   This may be less than the size of the buffer (capacity).
    /// </summary>
    public int Length
    {
        get { return _length; }
        private set
        {
            Contract.Requires(value >= 0);
            Contract.Requires(value <= _buffer.Length);
            Contract.Requires(value >= CurrentByte);
            Contract.Ensures(_length <= _buffer.Length);
            _length = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The raw buffer encapsulated by the encoder.
    /// </summary>
    protected internal Byte[] Buffer
    {
        get { return _buffer; }
        private set
        {
            Contract.Requires(value != null);
            Contract.Requires(value.Length >= _length);
            _buffer = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reserve space in the encoder buffer for the specified number of new bytes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytesRequired">The number of bytes required</param>
    protected void ReserveSpace(int bytesRequired)
    {
        Contract.Requires(bytesRequired > 0);
        Contract.Ensures((Length - CurrentByte) >= bytesRequired);

        //Check if these bytes would overflow the current buffer););
        if ((CurrentByte + bytesRequired) > Buffer.Length)
        {
            //Create a new buffer with at least enough space for the additional bytes required
            var newBuffer = new Byte[Buffer.Length + Math.Max(bytesRequired, CapacityDelta)];

            //Copy the contents of the previous buffer and replace the original buffer reference
            Buffer.CopyTo(newBuffer, 0);
            Buffer = newBuffer;
        }

        //Check if the total length of written bytes has increased
        if ((CurrentByte + bytesRequired) > Length)
        {
            Contract.Assume(CurrentByte + bytesRequired <= _buffer.Length);
            Length = CurrentByte + bytesRequired;
        }
    }

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void GlobalRules()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(_buffer != null);
        Contract.Invariant(_length <= _buffer.Length);
        Contract.Invariant(_currentByte >= 0);
        Contract.Invariant(_currentByte <= _length);
    }
}
```

The main thing I noticed is that placing invariants on properties gets messy, but seems to solve more easily with invariants on fields.  It was also important to place appropriate contractual obligations in the property accessors.  I'll have to keep experimenting and see what works and what doesn't.  It's an interesting system, but I'd definitely like to know more if anybody has a good 'cheat sheet' on how the prover works.

Comment: +1 for toughing it out.  I tried really hard to use code contracts in our new product, but eventually had to back them out because they were getting to be very cumbersome, not to mention slow to compile.  They're really neat as a mental exercise though, and I enjoyed the mental puzzle they presented.

Comment: My experimental goal is to take a relatively small in-house utility library, fully spec it out with contracts and then use Pex to generate tests.  My explorations have already uncovered some corner cases not caught by our existing tests, so I'm definitely interested to see how this progresses.  So far I haven't noticed any major build time issues, but it might just be too small of a code base.  It does take the background static analyzer quite a while to prove things though.

Comment: Just a note; you can use auto-props with CC... just add a class invariant and it will be added as a pre-/post-condition.

Comment: @Porges, I was having a lot of trouble getting the prover to work properly when using auto-props and placing the constraints in the class invariant.  I'll have to experiment some more.

Comment: I just tried with your example and it doesn't seem to fully work... I've posted on the MSDN CC forum. :)

Comment: Turns out it was a bug: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/codecontracts/thread/4256d386-2819-413e-83b6-4853a2fea30b ... should be easier to code up when this is fixed :)

Comment: @Porges, Thanks for the follow-up on all that; it does seem that Code Contracts still has a few kinks that need to be ironed out.  I'll keep at it, as I think it's an extremely valuable tool, even if only as a conceptual aid to guide me through explicitly specifying all of my assumptions.